Что здесь приложение, а что определяемое слово? Нужно ли тире?
При проверке сочинения ЕГЭ столкнулась вот с таким предложением:
"Чтобы привлечь внимание читателя, писатель знакомит нас с командиром батареи — капитаном Николаенко, который задаётся вопросом..."
Я считаю, что тут не нужно тире, т. к. интонационно пауза не напрашивается. Также мне кажется, что тут есть классическое приложение "командиром батареи", указывающее на должность персонажа, а также следом идёт гибрид (слияние приложения "капитаном" с именем "Николаенко", которое можно в целом воспринимать как определяемое выражение). Так ли это?
Вот если поменять местами "капитана Николаенко" и "командира батареи", то обособление второго уже кажется логичным.
Заранее благодарю за ответы!

командир - это капитан, видимо в этом смысл тире. капитан - лидер, шеф, командир, дословно "голова"/"глава"... так что, или нужно обособлять, или ставить тире.

Если в тексте использовано обособление имени собственного с помощью тире, то его нужно, вероятно, сохранить,  так как ошибки в нем нет.
Чтобы привлечь внимание читателя, писатель знакомит нас с командиром батареи — капитаном НиколАенко, который задаётся вопросом...
Второе тире опущено, при этом при прочтении предложения увеличенной паузы нет, но делается очень короткая пауза. Поэтому главная часть предложения читается фактически как одна фраза.
Пояснение

Автор обособляет приложение, выраженное именем собственным, чтобы обозначить его пояснительный характер, что определяется по контексту. У Розенталя: § 19. Обособленные приложения, пункт 6

Обособление возможно не только запятыми, но и тире. Пункт 10. При обособлении приложений вместо запятой употребляется тире: 1) если перед приложением можно вставить слова а именно (без изменения смысла).

Второе тире опускается перед  запятой в данном тексте (перед с. с. который):
Примечание. Одно тире (первое или второе) перед запятой 
1) если по условиям контекста после обособленного 
приложения ставится запятая: Если бы он привлёк к 
решению вопроса свой прибор — весы, то понял бы источник 
ошибки; 


Вариант без обособления также возможен при отсутствии пояснительного значения:


Чтобы привлечь внимание читателя, писатель знакомит нас с командиром батареи капитаном Николаенко, который задаётся вопросом...
Этот вариант представляется более удачным, так как интонационно мало отличается от варианта с тире. То есть такое обособление при чтении мало что дает, и можно ввести всю информацию о персонаже сразу, без пояснительного значения. А вот менять их местами не стоит, если автор считает главной именно должность, а не имя персонажа, к тому же тогда будет встреча  двух запятых (обособление запятыми и запятая в предложении).

О грамматике. Здесь имя собственное Николаенко является определяемым существительным, перед которым стоят неоднородные приложения командиром батареи капитаном (должность и звание). Таким образом, при отсутствии обособления имя человека является в предложении дополнением (знакомит с кем), а остальные существительные — приложением.

Но если автор решает обособить сочетание капитан Николаенко, то оно становится обособленным приложением и в структуру основного сообщения не входит. Сравнить: Вошла сестра Маша. — Вошла сестра, (а именно) Маша. Интонация во всех случаях соответствует выбранному знаку препинания.
Из правила Розенталя:
  6. Собственное имя лица или кличка животного выступает в 
  роли обособленного приложения, если поясняет либо 
  уточняет-нарицательное существительное (перед таким 
  приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить слова а 
  именно, то есть, а зовут его): Дочь Дарьи Михайловны, 
  Наталья Алексеевна, с первого взгляда могла не понравиться 
  (Т.); 
  Примечание. Во многих случаях возможна двоякая пунктуация, 
  в зависимости от наличия/отсутствия пояснительного оттенка 
  значения и соответствующей интонации при чтении: 
  Один только казак, Максим Голодуха, вырвался дорогою из 
  татарских рук (Г.); Елизавета Алексеевна поехала погостить 
  к брату, Аркадию Алексеевичу; 
  Вошла её сестра Мария; Сегодня я и друг мой Серёжа уезжаем 
  на юг; Выступал староста группы Коля Петров; По дороге нам 
  встретился главный инженер Жуков.

Дополнительная информация по теме Как отличить приложение от подлежащего
